# Aerospike connect using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, aerospike

I want to connect to Aerospike server (using IP address:3000) using JavaScript only, without any between layer (like node.js). Does anyone have a clue, how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It impossible because JS cant create direct connect to RAW Socket.